# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.graphics.Point.setAntiAlias(boolean)' on a null object reference

Tags: codenameone

Within a Codename1 app, I'm getting a CrashReport: java.lang.NullPointException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.graphics.Point.setAntiAlias(boolean)' on a null object reference.  This seems to occur after I invoke a "show()" on the main form of my application.

Note that the code runs fine in the simulator, but consistently gets this error prior to doing the "show()" on Android.

Interestingly, if I put a Dialog like this:
        Dialog.show("Wait a sec", "Showing interrupt point", "OK", null);
before the .show(), and then click "OK", then everything runs well with no exceptions at all.

But a sleep(5000) instead of the Dialog does not help - still get the exception.  So it at least seems like its not a race condition.

I have try-catches wrapped around all of the potentially offending code, and have NOT been able to isolate this.  It always gets caught by the CrashReport, and only when running on the Android device.

Any ideas?

Comment: Voting to close for lack of actual code. Please [edit[ your question to include the actual error, in full, and the code that causes the error.

Comment: Again, I have not been able to isolate the actual code that causes the error.  But the symptom should mean something to the Codename1 team?

Comment: At some point in your code you call `setAntiAlias` on a Point object, at that point in time, the point object is null. Find it.

Comment: Not so, at least not directly.  Codename1 is a cross-platform environment that translates from Java into both Objective C (for IOS) and Java (difference classes) for Android.  CN1 undoubtedly invoked setAntiAlias, but my code does not.  But good point.  I will try to find setAntiAlias within the CN1 code itself.

Comment: Note that the code reference above should read android.graphics.Paint.setAntiAlias(boolean).  So, somehow the "Paint" object is set to null within the CN1 classes.  I'm not sure what I could do to make that happen, but I am using quite a few layout managers for this form.  Thoughts?

Comment: Ok, I *think* I have tracked this down to the old deprecated CN1 Maps.  Now that Google native maps allows overlays, I guess its time to make the switch.

Comment: The symptoms to this one are pretty strange (i.e. workaround with a Dialog), and it would be interesting to have an explanation.  However, since deprecated cn1 (Map) code has seemingly been implicated, I'm going to let this one go and replace this code with the latest Google native maps code.  If it recurs, I will post another question.

Comment: That could still be an EDT violation that causes the port to misbehave. If you sleep that probably means you are working on a separate thread which can cause weird device specific issues I suggest going over this: https://www.codenameone.com/manual/edt.html and running with the edt violation detection tool on in the simulator

Comment: Also you can connect the device with a cable to DDMS so you can see the exception stack although in this case it probably won't be very helpful

Answer (score 1):

The symptoms to this one are pretty strange (i.e. workaround with a Dialog), and it would be interesting to have an explanation. However, since deprecated cn1 (Map) code has seemingly been implicated, I'm going to let this one go and replace this code with the latest Google native maps code. If it recurs, I will post another question then.